# Print values from db with secure PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm very new in PHP. This is what I always did. I have a page with various projects. Each project have a link that goes to the description of each, for ex: www.example.com/project.php?id=1

In the page project y take the variable and search in the db (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id

then I put for example `echo $row['name']`

Well, a buddy told me that I have to make a PDO query because what I was doing was not secure. I'm wondering if someone can help me with the code. This is what I did till now, but I can't move forward.

Many thanks in advance!

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dateBaseHost.';dbname='.$dateBaseName, 
$dateBaseUsername, $dateBasePassword);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//simple query and binding with results
$query = $db->prepare(" SELECT * FROM grafica WHERE ID = :id ");
```

Answer (score 5):

Your above code looks good. Now you just need to bind to the `:id` parameter with **[`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)**, then execute the query with **[`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)**. You can retrieve the result with **[`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)**.

```
// Simple query and binding with results
$value = 1;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grafica WHERE ID = :id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $value);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

// Output all the results
print_r($result);

// Loop over the results to output a specific result
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: This is literally how it works? I think in fetchAll there is an extra ")" is that right? And is showing me an error where the     echo "$row['id']"; Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Comment: You are correct; there was a typo ;) I've fixed that up now :)

Comment: `bindParam` isn't going to work with a static value like `'1'`. You'll need `bindValue` for that or assign the value to a variable

Comment: Honestly didn't realise you couldn't do that directly -- Updated to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

So I have to send the id through the url like www.mysite.com?id=1 and the code should be like this?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dateBaseHost.';dbname='.$dateBaseName, 
$dateBaseUsername, $dateBasePassword);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Simple query and binding with results
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM grafica WHERE ID = :id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();

// Output all the results
print_r($result);

// Loop over the results to output a specific result
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo $row['id'];
}
```